# Is it better to store this information in an array or database?

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays

I am creating a list and each item contains 3 properties: Caption, link, and image name. The list will be a "Trending now" list, where a related picture about the article is shown, a caption to the article, and a link to that article. Would it be best to store this information in an array or a database? With an array I could update the list, by adding 3 new properties, and removing the last 3. With a database, I could make a form where I submit the 3 properties and it'll update on its own without me touching the code. Would it be better to make this system in a Javascript array, or database? Wouldn't it be better to make it into an array for faster speeds? The list will have 10 items, each item has 3 properties.

Comment: You have to store the information somewhere…if it's just in an array, it's only accessible on the local machine.

Comment: you can store it in json format

Comment: @royhowie Wouldn't the data be available permanently if I update the array code of my file?

Comment: hard-coded data in the form of Arrays is a very fast way to get info to JS. it's so good they gave it a name: JSON. DBs are good for searching, organizing complex relationships between things, and live-updating among many users, but if you just need data storing, Arrays are perfect.

Answer (score 0):

For a list of 10 items, you can definitively go with a simple Array. If you need to store a bigger amount of data, than try localStorage.

Whichever solution you use, keep in mind that it will always be processed and stored in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Razor - your question touches many principles of programming. Being a beginner myself, I remember having had exactly those questions not too long ago.
That is why I answer in that 'beginner's' spirit:

if this were to be a web application then your 'trending now list' might be written as a ul list with li items in a section in an index.html in html code with css.style to style the list and your page.

Then you might use javascript, jQuery, d3.js etc. or other languages such as php to access and do something  with data from those html elements.

pseudo-code example to get a value from an element:

```
var collectedValue = $("#your_element_id).value;
```

To get values into an array you would loop over your item.values pseudo-code:

```
 for (all item.value collectable){
 my_array.push(item.values); 
 }
```

Next you would have to decide how to store and retrieve values and or arrays.

This can be done client side, more or less meaning: it stays with the browser you are working in. Or server side, meaning more or less your browser interacts with a server on an 'other' computer to save and retrieve data.

Speed is an issue when you have huge data sets, otherwise it is not really an issue; certainly not for a short list. In my thinking speed is a question for commercial applications.

In case you use a database, then you have to learn the database language and manage the database, access to it, and so on. It is not overly complex in mysql and php ( that is how I started ) but you would have to learn it.

In html/css/javascript solutions others have pointed out 'JSON', which is often used for purposes such as yours.
'localStorage' is very straight forward, but has its limitations. Both these are easily understandable.

To start, I myself worked through simple database examples about mysql/php
Then I improved my html/css experience. Then I started gaining experience with javascript.
Best would be if you would enable yourself to answer your questions yourself:

1. learn  principles of html/css to present your trending now list
2. learn  principles of javascript to manipulate your elements
3. Set up a server on your computer to learn how to interact with server side ( with MAMP or such packages)
4. learn principles of mysql/php
5. learn about storage options client or server side

It is fun, takes a while, and your preferences and programming solutions will depend on your abilities in the various languages.

I hope this answer is not perceived as being too simplistic or condescending; your question seemed to imply that such 'beginner's talk' might be helpful to you.